# How to develop sso with Java and IBM Cloud IAM

Tags: ibm-cloud, single-sign-on, trigonometry, ibm-iam

I have been developing a Java App that uploads some files on IBM Cloud Object Storage. To upload this file, now, I need to use the api key and api secret for each user. 
Is it possible to obtain automatically this pair of key through a Single Sign On flow with IBM username/email and password? In this way users can access to my app through their username and password and the service try to obtain necessary keys to use COS and other IBM services.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that your users will have access to the COS bucket?

Comment: Yes, users have access to COS bucket. I manage their permissions with IAM group and policies.